# error in order egrep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is part of a script; this part is supposed to check if there is a string in the first word twice or more that is also in the last word twice or more (in a row at the last word).

```
echo "$first $last" | egrep "(([^ ]+)[^ ]* \1[^ ]* )[ ]* \2\2 * "
```

The error is:

```
egrep: Invalid back reference
```

Comment: You can't reference a group inside which you are. `\1` matches the first (capturing) group starting with the first `(`.

Answer (score 4):

Picking apart your expression:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^ ]+                    any character except: ' ' (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^ ]*                    any character except: ' ' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^ ]*                    any character except: ' ' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [ ]*                     any character of: ' ' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \2                       what was matched by capture \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \2                       what was matched by capture \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```

It appears that you are trying to refer to `\1` before the definition of what is captured into `\1` is complete.

Comment: I don't like complex regular expressions but you're impressive.  What a good explanation that probably doubled my regexp knowledge!

Comment: The nice thing about regular expressions is that while they can accrete to hideously complex monstrosities, they are easy to tease apart into their component parts.  Happy to have helped! (: